# Adding mm:ss times when expressed as TEXT

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, text-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have a series of numbers that, for a reason out of my control I can not change, are expressed as plain text strings on google sheets.

The numbers are supposed to be minute second. `mm:ss`. For the life of me, I can not figure out how to add them together. Does anyone have any ideas?

The desired result would be something like:

```
01:50
06:10
60:00
"Random text"
""
05:30
```

Resulting time `73:30` OR `01:13:30` (I'm not picky about which one)

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TIME(0, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.*):"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ":(.*)")))), "hh:mm:ss"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TIME(0, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.*):"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ":(.*)")))), "[m]:ss"))
```

[image: 0]